# How to create a counter

Tags: php, html, counter

I would like to create a counter in which I can set a starting number and that every second increases by one.
I need the counter to be integrated into a page of my website.
I have no idea how to create it.
Thank you everyone

Comment: Show the code you have made.

Comment: I am sorry, I have not created a code

Answer (score -1):

This is a javascript question.

```
var i=0;
setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    //add_code to update html text to i
,1000);
```

Comment: how is this a js question? the op didn't tag as such and a serverside method is by far much better than a client-side and for a few reasons. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Because the serverside can't update the html every damn second. You should probably read the question before posting and yes his tags are wrong.

Comment: sure it can; it's called ajax and it relies on an http request. Mind your language also.

Comment: And ajax is javascript! So all in all Im right. Just accept your mistake instead of pushing it further.